# In Java/Spring, how do you setup the hashmap to append the query string?

Tags: spring, redirect, dictionary, query-string

in **spring-config/applicationContext-mapping.xml**:

I have this code fragment:

```
<bean id="unused-url-quick" class="java.util.HashMap">
    <constructor-arg>
    <map>
          <entry key="/page.html" value="/otherpage.html"/>
            ...
        </map>
```

I can an add an entry key to redirect from one page to another.

Using this same method how can I pass a querystring parameter to the otherpage.html...

```
<bean id="unused-url-quick" class="java.util.HashMap">
    <constructor-arg>
    <map>
      <entry key="/page.html?qs=1" value="/otherpage.html?qs=1"/>
        ...
    </map>
```

..where the query string key=value pairs vary?

Comment: Where is this map used? As part of some view resolver / controller? If it's one of the standard ones provided by Spring, which one?

Comment: I believe it is for view resolver

Comment: I don't know any Spring built-in resolvers that would do something like this; is it something custom?

If so, that's where you need to look for your answer - it's not about how to specify query params in a map but rather how are they handled in your view resolver.

Comment: ok you're probably right here. I'm still trying to unwind/dissect the system setup here to figure out how its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not done at the Spring level.

Comment: This is reserved for answers use *add comment* where appropriate